# is a unique ubuntu version available for download exactly the same in all periods of time?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

I had been using ubuntu 16.04 LTS version since its release month. now i removed it and i want to reinstall it again.

i have the installation file from last year and i want to know is the installation file from last years exactly the same as Ubuntu 16.04 installation file witch is available for download from Ubuntu site now?

o updates such as recent gnome software updates and fixes are made over it?

Comment: The latest revision of 16.04 is 16.04.3 LTS, and this will be what is on the official site; last year's installation disc is probably less recent, but it may be quicker to use this than down-load another installation disc. After installation I would expect to install updates since this release, but you can elect to do this during the installation process itself, though I prefer not to, as it delays getting an operational installation, and network problems can mean that the process will need to be restarted. After installation, run `sudo apt update; sudo apt upgrade` to get the latest updates.

Comment: why didn't you put this in as an answer and commented it?

Comment: I've made it an answer now. I originally commented because I wasn't sure if I covered all the aspects of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest revision of 16.04 is 16.04.3 LTS, and this will be what is on the official site; last year's installation disc is probably less recent, but it may be quicker to use this than down-load another installation disc.

After installation I would expect to install updates since this release, but you can elect to do this during the installation process itself, though I prefer not to, as it delays getting an operational installation, and network problems can mean that the process will need to be restarted.

After installation, get the latest updates by running:-

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: from where you said that its 16.04.3? i did not see it on its website

Comment: The web-site should take you to https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop and this is clearly 16.04.3.